# Increment / Decrement value on Digital Crown rotation

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-3

I am able to get the events for the digital crown and I want to decrease the speed as on rotating a little crown calls multiple events. So, I want to achieve if there is about 30 degrees rotation in any direction I will increase or decrease the value. How can I do that?

```
func crownDidRotate(_ crownSequencer: WKCrownSequencer?, rotationalDelta: Double) {
if value > 0 {
   myValue = myValue + 1
} else if value < 0 {
   myValue = myValue - 1
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result in watchOS, you need to manage extra variable that tell us about Digital Crown rotated at some specific angle like,

```
let expectedMoveDelta = 0.523599 //Here, current delta value = 30° Degree, Set delta value according requirement.
var crownRotationalDelta = 0.0 

func crownDidRotate(_ crownSequencer: WKCrownSequencer?, rotationalDelta: Double) {

     crownRotationalDelta  += rotationalDelta
     if crownRotationalDelta > expectedMoveDelta { //Crown rotating in clock-wise direction 
         myValue = myValue + 1
         crownRotationalDelta = 0.0 
     } else if crownRotationalDelta < -expectedMoveDelta { //Crown rotating in anti clock-wise direction 
         myValue = myValue - 1
         crownRotationalDelta = 0.0 
     }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done.... I wonder if i am using a WKInterfaceTable, in this case, crown is not working properly.